# Can consecutive transactions be mined on same block?

Tags: nonce

Can consecutive transactions of same EOA (Externally Owned Account) be mined at same block as below?

TX1: nonce=0, Number_confrimed_Block=100
TX2: nonce=1, Number_confrimed_Block=100
TX3: nonce=2, Number_confrimed_Block=100

Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if this is possible, then the answer is yes it is possible for consecutive transactions from the same EOA to be in the same block. This can possibly happen if the miner receives all the three transactions in quick succession. The block will be valid if within the block, the order of the transactions are correct. This is because the [state transition](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#blockchain-and-mining) occurs sequentially in Ethereum.